# Implementing Next-Line Prefetching for n-way Set Associative Cache

Tags: c++, caching, architecture, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm currently working on the classic cache simulation project and could use a bit of help.
One of our tasks is to implement an N-way Set-Associative Cache with next-line prefetching and an LRU replacement policy. So far, the first and third parts of this task haven't been too much of an issue, I have a working N-way Set-Associative Cache and a working LRU policy. The next-line prefetching part is giving me some trouble however.

So in theory, I think I understand how next-line prefetching is supposed to work: We go to access our cache, accessing line *X*. Now while we're at it accessing line *X*, we're going to go ahead and bring *X+1* into the cache with  us, and now thanks to the principle of spatial locality, in the decently high likelihood *X+1* is sought for, we end up getting a hit and not a miss. Additionally, while we brought *X+1* into the cache, we updated our LRU so *X+1* is the most recently accessed block for that set.

The thing that actually has me hung up though is the actual way to implement it and the finer details. When we say *X* and *X+1*, what parts of the cache line are we referring to specifically? Are we supposed to add 1 to the index? the tag? the entire memory address? Also I know we have to be wary of overflows. The project specifies a 32 byte cache line size and a 16kb cache, so depending on where we add that 1, it appears that it can overflow and potentially mess with things, so we need to take care of that too and add an extra 1 somewhere I think, but I'm not too sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**TL;DR**: What is the *X* in *X+1*, are we supposed to add one to the entire address? only the tag bits? only the index? etc.

Comment: I presume `X` relates to "cache line", and therefore `X + 1` is "the next cache line". In other words, it would be the address divided by the size of the cache line. Probably. As always, coding questions described in words followed by "how do I implement this change in my code" are always unhelpful. The answer would likely be much more obvious if you showed your code.

Answer (score 0):

The next 32-byte cache line in the address space.  On a load for address X, the next line contains address `X+32` for a line size of 32.

Probably simplest to implement it as `prefetch(address + linesize)` to do the adding in linear address-space and make a separate call to a function that breaks up that address into tag / index.

But assuming a simple indexing function, that *is* equivalent to adding 1 to the index, with carry into the tag if the index wraps back to zero. Manually doing carry-propagation from a narrow add is no easier than redoing shift/and.